# Anaconda unicode error at prompt. UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 2105: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Anaconda unicode error at prompt. UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 2105: character maps to  Here is the screen capture at prompt [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3hEX.png)

This is the exception message I get when I just write "python".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 439, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 2105: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Were you expecting `ž`?  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: Sorry. I edited the original message